# Add tooltip in jobs to checkmark - what does the checkmark mean?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Please add a visual cue or tooltip on a checked job:

[image]

Considering there is no interface to manage your jobs / applications one needs to know what this checkbox means.

Answer (score 3):

It means you've already applied to that job. I've added a title so that it's shown as a tooltip.

Comment: Right but currently jobs are in limbo.  I have open jobs there for years...after a few years you forget you've even applied.  I know what it is for as I am a poweruser.  However, others may be new to jobs or like I said applied months or years ago and will never remember if they applied or not.  The tooltip is an indicator to help me realize that ahh yes I applied.  Thanks

Comment: @JonH yup, I agree it's an useful indicator, it will be deployed shortly :)